# Windows Store app webservice consume

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-8

I have a windows phone 7 app with following code

```
ServiceReference1.SMSWarriorServiceSoapClient ws = new ServiceReference1.SMSWarriorServiceSoapClient();
ws.BalanceCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.BalanceCompletedEventArgs>(ws_BalanceCompleted);
ws.BalanceAsync(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Password);
```

Now i want to make it also for Windows 8 store app. I try this

```
var client =  new ServiceReference1.SMSWarriorServiceSoapClient() ;
var result =  client.BalanceAsync("user", "pass");
resultDetails.Text = result.ToString ;
```

but with no luck
I also try the Await but I don't know how to use it

Comment: What's the return type of `BalanceAsync(...)` method? What kind of error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling the web service method from an event handle then use this.

```
private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var client = new ServiceReference1.SMSWarriorServiceSoapClient();
    var result = await client.BalanceAsync("user", "pass");
    resultDetails.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

If you are calling the web service method from a method then use this.

```
private async Task ServiceCall()
{
    var client = new ServiceReference1.SMSWarriorServiceSoapClient();
    var result = await client.BalanceAsync("user", "pass");
    resultDetails.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

Ensure you call method `ServiceCall()` with `await` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

if u use await then u must use async keyword or use Task

```
var client =  new ServiceReference1.SMSWarriorServiceSoapClient() ;
var result =  await client.BalanceAsync("user", "pass");
resultDetails.Text = result.ToString ;
```

for example:

```
// Put the keyword, async on the declaration of the event handler.
private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var respose=await <some async operation >
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand. The error is in the result.tostring not to await

Comment: I think this is what i'm doing var result =  await client.BalanceAsync("user", "pass");

Comment: var result = await client.BalanceAsync("user", "pass"); good and add async to event handler such as onpageload ,clickevent ,etc shall i know

Comment: where are u invoking this service reference (which event)

Comment: the result  will not get output unless await operation get completed that why result.toString() get error

Comment: I have 2 textboxes and 1 button
The code is in button click.
I'm calling the webservice to check is the user exists. If exists the service returns a number if not then some text
The webservice is on http://www.lexiconsoftware.gr/sms/service.asmx